# Guice best practices and anti-patterns

Tags: java, dependency-injection, design-patterns, guice

I'm not sure if there is merit to this question or not, but are there any best practices and anti-patterns specific to [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice)?

Please direct any generic DI patterns to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682551).

Comment: I'd encourage anyone interested in contributing to this question to check out the [Guice docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/guice/topics) topics instead.

Answer (score 31):

I have always felt that constructor injection to final fields is a best practice. It minimizes mutable state and makes the class easier to understand by making the class's formal dependencies explicit.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final MyDependency dependency;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(MyDependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if We have dozens of dependencies? The constructor would be terrible

Comment: having dozens of dependencies on a single class is probably a good indication that the class is responsible for too much and should be refactored.

Comment: If you expect to write a unit test then this is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 14):

There are some on the Guice project page.  Here's a link to the [first one](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/MinimizeMutability), and you can see the others in the sidebar.

That said, I think it would be great to see others posted and voted on here. Then we can write the best of them up for the Guice pages.