# Variable initialisation in if statment

Tags: java, initialization, local

Why this doesn't want compile, if in other condition like if(8>0) will

```
public class StartClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    boolean b = true;
    if (b) {
        i = 1;
    }
    System.out.println(i);//error
}
}
```

Comment: Because `i` is not necessarily initialized. The compiler doesn't realize that `b` will always be true.

Comment: It works with `(8>0)` because that is replaced with true. It will also work if you declare `b` as `final`.

Comment: See also [What is the design rational for “variable may not have been initialized”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283742/what-is-the-design-rational-for-variable-may-not-have-been-initialized)

Comment: thnks) final will solve

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

java doesn't give [initial value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to variable declared inside methods..

`int i` is declared inside the main method, so there is no default initial value for that...

if **b** never gets to be true then **i** never gets initialized,

So the compiler complains because it may happen that **i** has no value 
ergo: you are not going to be able to do `System.out.println(i);`