# Infinite child object type

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to create a Parent and Child class but A child class might contain Parent class, How can I do that in java?

For example:

```
ParentClass {
  ChildClass childClass;
}

ChildClass {
  ParentClass parentClass;
}
```

is this possible? and if possible, what is the term in Java?

Comment: Your code doesn't show any inheritance - also what is the problem with having a reference to a `ParentClass`?

Comment: it can be Parent has Child and Child has Parent and that Parent has child and that child has Parent

Comment: You said that, but where is the problem?

Comment: Did this compile and run? Did it do what you wanted? How would you go about using these objects? A clearer question with a real example will be easier to answer.

Comment: You can compose classes with whatever you want. You'd have a problem if class1 inherited from class2 and class2 inherited from class1, but as UnholySheep mentionned your code shows no inheritance.

Comment: Maybe my question is wrong, My scenario is: A have an atrribute of B but B can have an A and that A can have attribute B

Comment: Your question seems right. It's just that the answer is : yeah, you can do that. No problem. (that's no parent/child relationship though)

Comment: That's not a question. Did you actually try doing that?

Comment: Yes you can do it but it probably isn’t a good idea. I don’t know if there is a specific name. It’s quite tricky to initialise the objects though.https://stackoverflow.com/q/19808342/6253321

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize a circular dependency (final fields referencing each other)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808342/how-to-initialize-a-circular-dependency-final-fields-referencing-each-other)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible as the fields are null, creating one instance will never create its other classes instance.

The following will explode at run-time:

```
class ParentClass {
  ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
}

class ChildClass {
  ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass();
}

new ChildClass();
```

---

The following will explode too.

```
class ParentClass {
  ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass();
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

new ChildClass();
```

---

Or simply:

```
class ParentClass {
  ParentClass parentClass = new ParentClass();
}

new ParentClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

The question does not refer to inheritance at all. It's just the use of "child" and "parent" name that are confusing.

You are making a circular dependency where class child has a field to reference a parent and class parent has a field to reference a child.

This question has already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808342/how-to-initialize-a-circular-dependency-final-fields-referencing-each-other). The answer is either you use a factory to reference your field in the constructor :

```
class Parent {
    Child child;

    Parent(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}

abstract class Child {
    Parent parent;

    Child() {
        this.parent = constructParent();
    }

    protected abstract Parent constructParent();
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
        new Child(){
            protected Parent constructParent(){
                return new Parent(this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Either you affect your field later using setters :

```
class Parent {
    Child child;

    Parent() {}

    void setChild(Child child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
}

class Child {
    Parent parent;

    Child(){}

    void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String []args){
         Parent parent = new Parent();
         Child chill = new BChild();

         parent.setChild(child);
         child.setParent(parent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You are looking for the term Composition `has-a` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably confusing inheritance with composition.

In inheritance, a child class **is** a parent class (and more). It is produced with the `extends` keyword, as in the following code :

```
class Dog extends Animal { /*...*/ }
```

The `Dog` is an `Animal` and as such will inherit the parent class' public and protected methods, maybe such as `feed()`, `breed()`, etc. It can define other methods specific to the child class such as `bark()`.

This direction must be unidirectional, if a class `A` extends a class `B`, the class `B` can't extend the class `A` (their definition would recurse into an infinite loop : "What is a `Dog`? Well, to begin with, it's an `Animal` ; alright, what is an `Animal` ? Well to begin with, it's a `Dog`, etc.")

In composition, a class **has** a reference to an instance of another class. It is produced by using fields that reference instance of other classes, such as in the following code :

```
class Kennel {
    Director director;
    Set<Dog> dogs;
    //...
}
```

A `Kennel` has a `Director` and a set of `Dog`s.

In this case the relation between both classes can be bi-directional (a `Dog` can have a `Kennel` field) without any problem, and the relation actually isn't between classes but rather between instances (except if your fields are `static`, but let's not bother with that).