# Trying to optimise my code leads to infinite classes being created

Tags: java, android, class

I just started learning android java, but I'm not entirely new to programming. I'm trying to learn to write programs as optimised as possible. I read somewhere that an Activity class shouldn't contain more than around 500 lines of code, and it said something about helper classes, although I couldn't find more information about those on the Internet.

What i tried:
A simple app that asks for permission and uses a dialog to first let the user know that it will ask for permissions. I created a PermissionManager and a PopupManager class and tried to get them to work together, like this:

```
class PermissionManager extends Activity {

    PopupManager pM = new PopupManager();

    boolean cameraPerm = false; 

    // PermissionResult
    pM.showPopup(...) // asks for the next permission
}
```

```
class PopupManager extends PermissionManager {

    PermissionManager permM = new PermissionManager();

    // somewhere in showPopup() 
    if (permM.cameraPerm) {...}
}
```

Both of these classes are then also used in the MainActivity class. But since both classes create a new of the other class, this will continue forever until the app crashes.

My question is, how can I create multiple classes that "work" with eachother, so I can keep my code optimised and organised?

Since I couldnt find much of this on Google, I'd also appreciate site recommendations or other tutorials where I could learn more of this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PopupManager pM = new PopupManager(this);` and initialize `PopupManager.permM` in the `PopupManager` constructor?

Comment: `I read somewhere that an Activity class shouldn't contain more than around 500 lines of code` stop believing every nonsense you read "somewhere"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a circular dependency (final fields referencing each other)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808342/how-to-initialize-a-circular-dependency-final-fields-referencing-each-other) and [Circular dependency in Java constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3646113)